# Build Failed: No such module 'FirebaseCore'. Xcode Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, podfile

My project was running fine on a virtual machine but after migrating to Mac Mini M2, Xcode is not building the app. The error is No such module 'FirebaseCore' and I have tried almost every solution available on stackoverflow and github. Still the same issue. Also, my project is running fine and building app on Android Studio.

Here is how my Podfile looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  use_modular_headers!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
#   target 'RunnerTests' do
#     inherit! :search_paths
#   end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple issues including pod files were not properly getting installed. Making sure that `pod init` and `pod install` hadn't any errors, modified the `Debug.xcconfig` file with the following lines:

```
#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
```

and then modified the `Release.xcconfig` with the following lines:

```
#include? "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig"
```

both the `Release.xcconfig` and `Debug.xcconfig` files are available in `ios/Flutter/` directory.